# "Extended" depth-first search in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, depth-first-search, shortest-path

I know how to implement depth-first search algorithm in C++, but I need an "extended version". So, I have a map

```cpp
map<int, map<int,int> > tree;
```

that for any vertex it returns a map with adjacent vertices as keys and (important for my program) edge indexes as values. The root of the tree is first (1) vertex. So, here is my code:

```cpp
stack<int> s;
for(const auto &pair : tree[1]) s.push(pair.first);
while(!s.empty()) {
    if(!visited[s.top()]) {    //it's just bool array
        roads[s.top()] = {0}; // ???
        for(const auto &pair : tree[s.top()]) s.push(pair.first);
    }
    s.pop();
}
```

What I need to do is create a vector of vectors in which, for every vertex, I'll have a complete path (expressed as edge indexes).

For example for graph like that:

```
       1
      /  \
(i=2)/    \(i=1)
    /      \
   2       3
           /\
          /  \
    (i=3)/    \(i=4)
        /      \
       4        5
```

I would like to have something like this:

```cpp
vector< vector<int> > roads = {{},{},{2},{1},{1,3},{1,4};
```

because `roads[0]` does not exist, `roads[1]` too, and for every other we have path expressed as edge indexes.

**EDIT**

In other words what I want to do:
For every vertex in a given tree I want to know a path from root to this vertex. Every edge in this tree has its own number, so path would be expressed as a vector or set (for simplicity's sake, I don't care at all about the order of edges).

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? What's the question here exactly? What is `roads` (input to the algorithm) and expected output?

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @ggorlen no, the `roads` is not an input.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie thank you very much for information about this. I realized that it is indeed an XY Problem, so please, look at the EDIT.

Comment: Your edit doesn't explain the purpose of all of this. Why do you need to do this? Just for fun or are you trying to solve some sort of problem? Please provide context. What's the input to the "problem"/algorithm (whatever that is)? `tree` is discussed at top but I don't see it used henceforth.

Comment: @ggorlen really sorry, I made a very stupid mistake (I mixed up the names) - already edited it. As for the purpose of this program, I just want to show on the screen what segments someone who wants to go from the root to each vertex will travel through.

Comment: @MichałDobranowski -- *For every vertex in a given tree* -- Then your "tree" is lacking in traversal techniques.  The problem you stated is easily solved by creating a binary tree from scratch and implement one of many traversal strategies, a task that is given to almost every starting CS student.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie but it's not binary tree - just graph with a root and no cycles. If it is not important, then I would love to if you could give me some names of this "traversal techniques" and I will try to solve this problem once again.

Comment: *but I need an "extended version"* -- The way you write a generic traversal routine is to traverse to the entry, and then call a function object provided by the user that processes the current entry.  If you rewrote your code to take another parameter that provides this object, then the problem is practically solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"graph with no cycles" is also known as a tree.

You want to have a list with all the sequences of edge labels that represent a path from root to some vertex?

Pseudocode for a traversal (I guess this would qualify as a `preorder` traversal):

```
void collect(node, //current node
    labels, //labels of edges leading to node
    &paths //all the paths collected so far, writeable, contains results
) {
    paths.add(labels);
    foreach ((neighbor_node, edge_name) in (unvisited neighbors of node)) {
        labels.add(edge_name);
        collect(neighbor_node, labels, paths);
        labels.remove(edge_name);                
    }
}

start with collect(root, empty_list, empty_list);
```

Comment: To be perfectly accurate a graph without cycles is a forest, but let's not get into technicalities here...